# GetPastEvents and string topic - Error: invalid argument 0: hex has invalid length 160 after decoding; expected 32 for topic

Tags: web3js, events

Being "token" below a contract instance, i do:

```
token.getPastEvents('OperationEvent', {fromBlock:68000000, filter: {productId: '0xe69cc33407fbe7f7d9bcc423d83da743843bcae7e19a7d20bfd38170f30f53f0'}})
```

Getting:

```
Error: invalid argument 0: hex has invalid length 160 after decoding; expected 32 for topic
```

The hex string sent is the result of "web3.utils.sha3()" for the original string topic. If i request all events from that contract i can see that the topic reported in the event i'm looking for perfectly matches the hex string i'm sending.

I suppose i'm just generating the topic the wrong way, but can't find anything in the docs or googling. ¿Any clue on how to get this right (filtering past events of a contract by an string topic)?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

token.getPastEvents('OperationEvent',
{
fromBlock: 68000000,
topics: [, '0xe69cc33407fbe7f7d9bcc423d83da743843bcae7e19a7d20bfd38170f30f53f0']
}).then((events: any) => {
console.log(events);
).catch((error: any) => {
console.log(error);
});

topics[0] is empty for the 'address' index,
and your "productId hex" should has the same index of your indexed "productId" param;

for example if your event is event OperationEvent(string indexed productId, ...)
topic should be => topics: [, '0xe69cc33407fbe7f7d9bcc423d83da743843bcae7e19a7d20bfd38170f30f53f0']

if your event is event OperationEvent(indexed param, string indexed productId, ...)
topic should be => topics: [, , '0xe69cc33407fbe7f7d9bcc423d83da743843bcae7e19a7d20bfd38170f30f53f0']